# Technical Drawing: Labelling a component that's not part of my design but integral to my system

Tags: technical-drawing, drawings

I am creating a technical drawing of a system I created. Let's call my system, system X. System X is a mounting mechanism for already invented system Y. System Y is customizable, however, system X is a general mechanism that can be fitted to any system Y.

My question is, when labelling my technical drawing, which includes a physical outline of system Y (otherwise the paper would have a lot of blank space), how can I articulate that my general depiction of system Y is replaceable with any customized version of system Y?

I am creating other drawings that detail the mechanisms of X up close without Y, however, in the case of my question, I am trying to create an overview drawing of what system X would look like when applied.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a great question because references like this can be confusing. However it is not very specific and it would likely yield highly opinionated replies. As far as my opinion goes, your drawings need to be clear and provide the complete nessecary information. Often times industry standards will be available and expected, otherwise use your judgement and some language skills to make a clear and complete drawing.

Comment: Thank you @ShadowMan. I tried to keep the question general for this site. I definitely agree with your take on it and try to keep it as clear as possible. I'm just looking for the convention on articulating the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the paper has a lot of blank space without drawing Y, then you can draw X at a bigger scale to fill it up, or use smaller paper!

If Y is physically bigger than X (which seems possible, if X is just a mounting system) you might want to add a reduced scale "sketch" drawing showing how X and Y are assembled.

If Y could be any component with a standard type of mount (e.g. any make of TV with a VESA standard mounting) explain that in a text comment, and just draw a "generic" version of Y in your assembly sketch drawing.

Comment: Thank you @alephzero. Y is physically larger than X, so I will take your advice and explain that I have drawn a generic version of Y.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use dashed lines for things that are in the image for reference, or not directly part of the item in the drawing. But in general adding something because you have blank space seems redundant. Add something if it makes things clearer.

It is also perfectly ok to write instructions and explanations. Drawings are human readable after all. So you can do prettymuch what you want as long as your clear about it. But then being clear is about the hardest thing on earth... Which is why deviating too much from convention is problematic.